# Deaggregate into single unit level

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table that I need to break apart or deaggregate:

`Order` Table:

```
Order Id Item   Qty
O1       A1      5
O2       A2      1
O3       A3      3
```

Please provide SQL which will explode the above data into single unit level records as shown below:

Desired Output:

```
Order Id    Item    Qty
O1          A1       1
O1          A1       1
O1          A1       1
O1          A1       1
O1          A1       1
O2          A2       1
O3          A3       1
O3          A3       1
O3          A3       1
```

How could I do this in Teradata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either JOIN to a table with numbers from 1 to n using `on n between 1 and Qty` (resulting in a *Product Join*) or utilize `EXPAND ON`:

```
select OrderId, Item, 1
from tab
expand on period (current_date, current_date + Qty) as pd
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach with a recursive cte.

```
with recursive cte(orderid,item,qty,val) as 
        (select orderid, item, qty, 1
         from t --this is your tablename
         union all
         select c.orderid, c.item, c.qty-1, c.val
         from t
         join cte c on t.orderid=c.orderid and t.item=c.item and c.qty>1
        )
select orderid,item,val as qty
from cte 
order by 1,2
```

Or with a numbers table (Generate all numbers = max quantity you can have)

```
with recursive cte(num) as (select 1 num
                            union all
                            select num+1 from cte where num < 1000 --change this to max quantity
                            )
select orderid, item, 1 as qty
from t
join cte c on t.qty >= c.num
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using replicate and string_split

```
select order_id, item, value
from (
select order_id, item, 
iif(quantity = 1, '1', concat('1',replicate(',1',(quantity-1)))) as split_quant
from orders) a
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(split_quant,',') ;
```

for more info on string_split : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Well, this question is tagged with `teradata` and `sql`, the latter is not a abbreviation for `sql server`, but `Standard SQL`. Both Teradata and Standard SQL support neither `iif` nor `cross apply` nor `string_split`.

Comment: SQL basically encompasses a broad spectrum of custom vendors. I was trying to find a MS SQL Server solution for a question similar to this. So, if someone else is in a similar scenario looks here, this'll be helpful rather than re-posting.  Also, i found a different approach in Oracle(https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement). Posting this here to improve the collective knowledge base. Also, thank you for the teradata approach.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with main1 as(
select orderid,item, qty, rownum rn from orders)
select orderid,item, '1' from (select * from 
main1
where rn = 1) 
connect by level <= qty
union all
select orderid,item,'1' from (select * from 
main1
where rn = 2) 
connect by level <= qty
union all
select orderid,item,'1' from (select * from 
main1
where rn = 3) 
connect by level <= qty
;
```